# How can I convert a string[] into a dictionary<int, string> using a separate int[] as the key set?

Tags: c#, linq

I know that Linq offers the `ToDictionary(key, value)` method, and I'm sure there's a way to be able to do what I'm trying to achieve but I can't quite figure it out.

I have two arrays, the first being `conditionalIds`, which is simply an `int[]` that stores a number of Ids, the second array is a `string[]` called `conditionalAnswers`. I essentially want to combine and map these two arrays so that each of the Ids stores in conditionalIds maps to the correct answer.

```
var conditionalIds = _currentRuleSet.MultiConditionalQuestionIds;
var conditionalAnswers = _currentRuleSet.MultiConditionalQuestionAnswers;
var map = conditionalAnswers.ToDictionary(conditionalIds, x => x[]);
```

However I'm not sure how to structure the Linq query to achieve this.

Comment: why linq? do both lists have the same number of values?

Comment: How do you know what is the correct answer of a given id?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming both lists have the same number of items and they are in the correct order, you want to use Linq [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8), for example this will give you an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type:

```
var map = conditionalIds.Zip(
    conditionalAnswers, 
    (id, answer) => new { id, answer });
```

And if you really want a dictionary:

```
var dictionary = map.ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x.answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ans given by @SeM is correct, but one thing is that question id array should have unique values.

```
    int[] queId={6,4,9,2,10};
string[] answers ={"Ans1", "Ans3","Ans4","Ans16","Ans18"} ;
Dictionary<int, string> queAnsBank=answers.select((value,index)=>new{Key=queId[index],Value=value}).ToDictionary(i=>i.Key,i=>i.Value);
```

You can also achieve this by for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like target dictionary could be constructed as:

```
        Dictionary<int, string> map = conditionalIds.ToDictionary(
            keySelector: id => id,
            elementSelector: id => conditionalAnswers[id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to map based on `conditionalAnswers` and `conditionalIds` indices, you can do something like this:

```
var map = conditionalAnswers
          .Select((s, i) => new { Key = conditionalIds[i], Value = s })
          .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
```

References: [Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)